# How to use swipe to change the label of specific row in tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

In `ViewDidLoad` of table view controller, I first added SwipeGuesture and handler **`"Swipecell"`**

```
     UISwipeGestureRecognizer *showExtrasSwipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] 
     initWithTarget:self action:@selector(Swipecell:)];
     showExtrasSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight| 
     UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
     [self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:showExtrasSwipe];

     //Here I define the handler:
     -(void)Swipecell:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gesture
     {
     //Taking gesture location
     CGPoint location = [gesture locationInView:_tableview];
     //Getting IndexPath for that location in tableview
     NSIndexPath *swipedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
     UITableViewCell *swipedCell  = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:swipedIndexPath];
     NSString *data = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:swipedIndexPath.row];
     //Setting the label of the cell
     [swipedCell.textLabel setText:data];
}
```

But it is working only for one first row. Can anybody help me in this or give me better solution? Don't forget to rate, if you like the question.

Comment: try swipe code in cellForRowAtIndexPath and add on cell ...

Comment: Tested your code. All works fine. Maybe yor problem is in typo:      NSString *datae =....  and   ....setText:data];

Comment: @Viper, but for me, only the text in first row is changing.

Comment: @oxigen, it's a typing mistake. I will edit it.

Comment: Do you checked to swipe all cells? I have 5 cells with textlable. When I swipe on any cell, IndexPath of first cell is only returned. Therefore, the label of only first cell changes.

Comment: Thanks, I found my mistake. Please rate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works... Tested on iOS 7.1 simulator

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    _tableview = (UITableView*)self.view;
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *showExtrasSwipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                 initWithTarget:self action:@selector(Swipecell:)];
    showExtrasSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight|
    UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:showExtrasSwipe];
}

-(void)Swipecell:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    CGPoint location = [gesture locationInView:_tableview];
    NSIndexPath *swipedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
    UITableViewCell *swipedCell  = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:swipedIndexPath];
    swipedCell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", swipedIndexPath.row];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 55;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @" ";
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add the swipe gesture in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method , so the gesture will be added to each cell.

Answer (score 0):

Change [gesture locationInView:_tableview] to [gesture locationInView:self.tableview]. I was refering to tableView outlet.